# Adding Files to Xcode Project to use Classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have created a new project in XCode 11.1 and when I downloaded a new charts.swift file my view controller which does not recognize the classes declared in the charts.swift files. I'm trying to create line graphs from user input in xcode using swift.

I tried hardcoding and using the UI to drag and drop with no luck. The drag and drop does not work and when hardcoded it says the class has not been declared previously.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  habituate3
//
//  Created by Christopher Hancock on 9/27/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Christopher Hancock. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var lineCharView: lineChartView!  <----- Error message here(
}
```

I should just be able to reference the class from this file I assumed.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@IBOutlet weak var lineCharView: LineChartView!`. Case matters. And you probably need an `import` for the framework you downloaded.

Comment: lineChartView or LineChartView? From framework Charts?